# How to setup Mockobjects and verify using Moq unit testing C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, moq, memorycache

My Cache Class is given below:

```
public class InMemoryCache : ICache
{
    private readonly ObjectCache _objCache = MemoryCache.Default;       

    public void Insert<T>(string cacheKey, T value)
    {
        _objCache.Add(cacheKey, value, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
    }
    public T Get<T>(string cacheKey)
    {
        if (cacheKey != null)
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(_objCache.Get(cacheKey), typeof(T));
        else
            return default(T);
    }
    public bool Exists<T>(string cacheKey)
    {
        return _objCache.Get(cacheKey) != null;
    }
}
```

And my Interface is

```
 public interface ICache
 {
    void Insert<T>(string cacheKey, T value);
    T Get<T>(string cacheKey);
    bool Exists<T>(string cacheKey);        
 }
```

I am using CacheFactory to call my InMemoryCache Class:

```
public class CacheFactory
{
    public static ICache Cache { get; set; }

    public static void Insert<T>(string cacheKey, T value)
    {
        Cache.Insert<T>(cacheKey, value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(string cacheKey)
    {
        return Cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
    }

    public static bool Exists<T>(string cacheKey)
    {
        return Cache.Get<T>(cacheKey) != null;
    }
}
```

I tried Mock Object like below and unable to get the result.

```
 [Fact()]
    public void CacheManager_Insert_Test()
    {
        string cacheKey = "GradeList";

        Mock<ICache> mockObject = new Mock<ICache>();
        List<Grade> grades = new List<Grade>
        {
            new Grade() {Id = 1, Name = "A*"},
            new Grade() {Id = 2, Name = "A"},
            new Grade() {Id = 3, Name = "B"},
            new Grade() {Id = 4, Name = "C"},
            new Grade() {Id = 5, Name = "D"},
            new Grade() {Id = 6, Name = "E"}
        };

        var mockedObjectCache = new Mock<ICache>();
        // Setup mock's Set method

        mockedObjectCache.Setup(m => m.Insert(cacheKey, grades));

       // How to get the Mocked data and verify it here

    }
```

Could someone check that my data insertion to cache is correct? Also how can I verify the cache data in unit test Moq? I am new to unit testing.

I am not able to verify since I am inserting data to object cache in my implementation class but mocking the interface. I suppose if I could relate both, It might be verifying. Not sure, it's just my guess.

### Updated Scenario

Consider having another class named "Convertor" which retrieves the Grade name based on the Grade ID from cache.

```
public class Convertor
{ 
    // Gets Grade ID and Displays Grade Name
    public string GetGradeName(int gradeId)
    {
        var gradeList = CacheFactory.Cache.Get<List<Grade>>(CacheKeys.Grades);
        return gradeList.Where(x => x.Id == gradeId).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

For this case, how can I verify this?  Since this method is using cache to retrieve value, I am not sure how to use mock here.

Comment: see the marked answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864076/mocking-static-methods

Comment: Hi Ioana, thanks for your update. I have checked the link. It tells that mocking static methods not possible. However, In my implementation class, InMemoryCache, it is non-static only. So, I dont think any trouble to mock up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the usage of mocks. The reason for using mocks is to test dependent classes without worrying on the dependencies.

Let's say you have the following class:

```
public class MyDependentClass {
    private readonly ICache _cache;
    public MyDependentClass(ICache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public int CountGradesInCache()
    {
        // Behavior depends on what's in the _cache object
        return _cache.Get<List<Grade>>("GradeList").Count;
    }
}
```

In order to test the above class you would have to mock the `ICache` object that is injected into the class in the constructor. In this case it would be sensible to use `Mock`:

```
    string cacheKey = "GradeList";

    Mock<ICache> mockObject = new Mock<ICache>();
    List<Grade> grades = new List<Grade>
    {
        new Grade() {Id = 1, Name = "A*"},
        new Grade() {Id = 2, Name = "A"},
        new Grade() {Id = 3, Name = "B"},
        new Grade() {Id = 4, Name = "C"},
        new Grade() {Id = 5, Name = "D"},
        new Grade() {Id = 6, Name = "E"}
    };

    var mockedObjectCache = new Mock<ICache>();
    // Setup mock's Set method

    mockedObjectCache.Setup(m => m.Get(It.Is<string>(cacheKey))).Return(grades);

    // Test that the dependent class acts correctly according to the grades that exist in the cache
    var myDependentClass = new myDependentClass(mockedObjectCache.Object);
    var gradesCount = myDependentClass.CountGradesInCache();

    Assert.AreEqual(6, gradesCount);
```

We mock the `ICache` to return 6 grades using the cache key "GradeList", which the dependent class relies on. We can now test that the method on `MyDependentClass` correctly returns the count in the cache. Likewise, you could make a test where the cache returns an empty list or `null` to check that the behavior of the dependent class is correct in all cases.

It seems in your example you want to test the `InMemoryCache` itself, in which case you would not want to mock anything. I would simply write tests like this:

```
var cache = new InMemoryCache();
var list = new List<Grade> { ... };
var cache.Insert("GradeList", list);

var cachedList = cache.Get<List<Grade>>("GradeList");

// Assert that the list retrieved from cache has the expected values.
```

> Updated scenario

For your updated scenario you cannot mock the cache, as it is retrieved by a static method on the `CacheFactory`. This is probably one of the best reasons to use dependency-injection for your dependencies, instead of instantiating them yourself in the class or instead of using static classes/methods.

What I would do to make the `Converter` class testable, would be to inject `ICache` into the class instead of using the `CacheFactory`:

```
public class Convertor
{ 
    private readonly ICache _cache;

    public Convertor(ICache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public string GetGradeName(int gradeId)
    {
        var gradeList = _cache.Get<List<Grade>>(CacheKeys.Grades);
        return gradeList.Where(x => x.Id == gradeId).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Now you would be able to mock the `ICache` and test the functionality of the `Convertor` class like I described above.

Comment: Could you please check the "Updated Scenario" and let me know how to mock the data? I really appreciate your great response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks tahatmat. Earlier I have not create any dependency classes to mock it, rather trying mock the same class. Now I got to understand the Mocking Concept. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confused in the conceptions.

If you want to (unit) test the Insert method of your InMemoryCache class, you definetaly should not mock the InMemoryCache.

Mocking is for the 3rd party classes used in the class you want to test.

In fact you have also a dependency in your insert method:

```
private readonly ObjectCache _objCache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

So, you should mock the ObjectCache instance somehow.

But this time ObjectCache must inherited from related interface in order to be used in Moq lib, i.e. IObjectCache

And you should use:

```
var mockObjectCache = new Mock<IObjectCache>();
...

//Verifying:
mockObjectCache.Verify(cache => cache.Add(It.IsAny<string>())).Should().Be(true);
```

However ObjectCache class is inherited from IEnumerable and IEnumerable>, so you cannot mock it directly. You should use a bridge interface (anti corruption layer) if you really need to mock.

Comment: Thanks Skynyrd! I also accept this solution as it is helpful for me to understand the mistake that I did. I am trying to mock the InMemoryCache Objects with out checking the dependency of ObjectCache I used. I also understand that its not the proper way of mocking the InMemoryCache Class.