# Mock a method in another static class c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want to ask the best way how to mock static a method in an another class. I know that mock is not working for a static class. Here is my Code so far. I don't want to call SearchSomething() at the time because it's external interaction

```
public ResponseBase GetData(string searchId)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new SearchRequest 
            {
                SearchId = searchId
            };
            var response = SearchLogic.SearchSomething(request);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ResponseBase.ExceptionHandling(e);
        }
    }

public class SearchLogic(){
    public static ResponseBase SearchSomething(SearchRequest request)
    {
        //Do Something
        return  new ResponseBase;
    }
}
```

This is my UnitClass

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitClass
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void PositiveSearchTest()
    {
        //arrange
        string searchId = "name";
        var expected = new SearchRequest();
        SearchtController search = new SearchtController();

        var staticMock = new Mock<SearchLogic>();
        staticMock.Setup(s => s.SearchSomething()).Returns(new ResponseBase());

        //act
         var actual = search.GetData(searchId);

        //assert
         Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: So it is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking Static Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864076/mocking-static-methods)

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya the mock is not working for some how

Answer (score 1):

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864076/mocking-static-methods) gives one way to solve this, my preferred solution would be different: modify `SearchLogic` so it is no longer static. After that, you can then mock it to your heart's content. Static methods are always a complete pain for unit testing; I try to use them only for situations where there is one and only one correct behaviour.

This obviously assumes you have the ability to modify `SearchLogic`. If you don't, see the linked question.

Comment: I use static beacuse I use it in many places, so it's easy for me use static to make as a singleton

Comment: If your DI framework doesn't make it trivial to inject an object into the places it's used, get a better DI framework :-)

Comment: I've change it so it no longer static. But can I mock the static method inside `SearchLogic`?

Comment: Make an interface and mock the interface rather than mocking the concrete implementation.